# Behavior of awk is different in my local system and RedHat 6.5

Tags: awk

RHEL 6.5 has GNU awk version as below

```
-bash-4.1$ awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7
```

And in windows 10 I see it as -

```
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.1.2)
```

AWK program uses awk built in variables `ARGV` and `ARGIND`. Is it something to with system locale in RHEL?

`base.csv`:

```
steve,tignor,ash,michael,jose,sam,joshua
0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

`file1`:

```
tignor,michael,jose
888,9,-2
```

`file2`:

```
ash,joshua
77,66
```

`merge.awk`:

```
#!/bin/awk
#!/bin/bash

ARGIND==1 && FNR==1{
  split($0, base, ",")
  printf("file,%s\n",$0)
}
ARGIND > 1 && FNR==1{
  split($0, names, ",")
  printf("%s", ARGV[ARGIND])
}
ARGIND > 1 && FNR==2{
  split($0, values, ",")
  for(i in names)
    line[names[i]] = values[i]
  for(i in base){
    if(base[i] in line)
      printf(",%s", line[base[i]])
    else
      printf(",0")
  }
  delete line
  print ""
}
```

Run from Linux results in incorrect order of values in file 1 and file 2

```
awk -f merge.awk base.csv file*

file,steve,tignor,ash,michael,jose,sam,joshua
file1,9,-2,0,0,0,888,0
file2,0,0,0,66,0,0,77
```

But from windows it works perfectly fine and the way I want it.

```
$ awk -f merge.awk base.csv file1.csv file2.csv
file,steve,tignor,ash,michael,jose,sam,joshua
A1.csv,0,888,0,9,-2,0,0
A2.csv,0,0,77,0,0,0,66
```

Any clues will be appreciated.

Comment: Please take a look at [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Iteration over keys of an array happens in arbitrary order. But see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html

Comment: Yes I understand that the awk uses associative array and iteration with indexes is not similar to other languages but wanted to understand why the behavior is different in 2 different system. Main logic remains the same.

Comment: The two versions of `gawk` use different hash functions or something along those lines, giving different orders of iteration.

Comment: Rightly said, but looking for a solution or work around to get this fixed. If we get to know how it process and what functions are involved internally then we can change the behaviour may be.

Comment: The `#!/bin/bash` in `merge.awk` is just a comment in the awk script, it's not a shebang specifying a shell if that's what you had in mind. You definitely do **not** want to try to learn what gawk does internally and somehow try to use that to affect behavior because then your script will probably break for the next release that does something different internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to write your code robustly and portably to work using any awk in any environment:

```
$ cat merge.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR == FNR {
    if (FNR == 1) {
        numOutFlds = NF
        for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
            names2nrs[$outFldNr] = outFldNr
        }
        print "file", $0
    }
    else {
        split($0,base)
    }
    next
}
{
    if (FNR == 1) {
        delete out2inFldNrs
        for (inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++) {
            outFldNr = names2nrs[$inFldNr]
            out2inFldNrs[outFldNr] = inFldNr
        }
    }
    else {
        printf "%s", FILENAME
        for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
            val = (outFldNr in out2inFldNrs ? $(out2inFldNrs[outFldNr]) : base[outFldNr])
            printf "%s%s", OFS, val
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f merge.awk base.csv file1 file2
file,steve,tignor,ash,michael,jose,sam,joshua
file1,0,888,0,9,-2,0,0
file2,0,0,77,0,0,0,66
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, Yes it is working in older awk environment.Great!

Comment: Hi Ed..Can this be solution be extended if we change row into columns ? Please take a look in question section for reference. Thanking in adv.

Comment: [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/361691) are strongly discouraged, put this question back the way it was and then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` arrays are hash tables, and iteration over their elements using `for (x in y)` happens in arbitrary order. GNU awk has a way to specify what order is used, though, with the [`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` setting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) (However, this only works with GNU awk 4.0 and newer; 3.X doesn't support it).

To iterate in ascending numeric order:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc" }
ARGIND==1 && FNR==1{
  split($0, base, ",")
  printf("file,%s\n",$0)
}
ARGIND > 1 && FNR==1{
  split($0, names, ",")
  printf("%s", ARGV[ARGIND])
}
ARGIND > 1 && FNR==2{
  split($0, values, ",")
  for(i in names)
    line[names[i]] = values[i]
  for(i in base){
    if(base[i] in line)
      printf(",%s", line[base[i]])
    else
      printf(",0")
  }
  delete line
  print ""
}
```

You can also iterate over the elements in order using a regular for loop, and have to do so in the old gawk version (Only relevant lines/blocks included):

```
...
basenum = split($0, base, ",")
...
for (i = 1; i <= basenum; i++) {
   if(base[i] in line)
      printf(",%s", line[base[i]])
    else
      printf(",0")
}
```

Comment: Shawn I dont think it is related to order. As I still see that the result is same when we use PROCINFO for sorted order.

Comment: @Rish Ah-ha. `sorted_in` was added in gawk 4.0. Your over a decade old version of gawk on the redhat machine is just too outdated. Try the second approach in my answer.

Comment: Iwas using comment instead of Answer tab. With PROFCINFO I did not get the expected result.

Comment: Yes I even thought of upgrading the rpm but to me surprisngly I see the official package  RHEL6.5 uses 3.7.1 which is bit surprising. I am looking to update the RPM and check results.

Answer (score 0):

@Shawn I tried using the regular c-style array for old GNU-awk style format.

```
ARGIND > 1 && FNR==2{
basenum = split($0, base, ",")
  for(i in names)
    line[names[i]] = values[i]
  for (i = 1; i <= basenum; i++) {
    if(base[i] in line)
      printf(",%s", line[base[i]])
    else
      printf(",0")
  }
  delete line
```

But results are not expected.

awk -f try.awk base.csv file*
file,steve,tignor,ash,michael,jose,sam,joshua
file1,0,0,0
file2,0,0